# Why do ndb.Model subclasses expand when populated?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

We have a Model defined like...

```
class Foo(ndb.Model): bar = ndb.TextProperty()
```

If I create, or `get`, an instance of `Foo` and name it `foo`, this works...

```
foo.populate(**{'SPAM': None})
```

This gives `foo` a new `SPAM` property.

I'd like to know how to make it raise an exception when a non-existent property is updated. I thought it's supposed to do that out the box.

For the record, the new properties are untyped too, so I can make `SPAM` be `5` then `"five"`, no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greg said: "Are your models Expando subclasses maybe?" That's what I asked myself at first, but in the actual code `ndb.Model` was the base class *we'd* used for everything else.

The app's `User` model is actually from the auth library we'd used, `webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models`, which presumably does use the `Expando` base class.

I tested this and every other model we have throws the expected exception.

**TL;DR** The `User` model in `webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models` uses the `Expando` base class. No real mystery.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is by design. You can do whatever you want with the `foo` object, like you can assign integer values to the `bar` as well and even delete this property if you want to. But when it comes to storing this value it will store only the properties that are defined in the model and have the correct type. The exception will be raised only if the type or value of the existing properties do not match their definition.

Comment: What you're saying is true; that is how it works, but in this case the data was being put to the db and gotten later, so it wasn't only bound to the instance, but was stored.

Answer (score 2):

Running the code you've posted will raise TypeError, as populate is expecting keyword-args that match property names, not a dict. Calling `foo.populate(**{"SPAM": None})` or `foo.populate(SPAM=None)` will raise

```
AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'SPAM'
```

Are you sure your actual code isn't different to your example? (Are your models Expando subclasses maybe?)

Comment: You're right, I forgot to use `**` to expand the kargs in the example, I've fixed that.